# How to let the program wait to receive the serial port data?

Tags: c#, serial-port

**Edited:**

I am working on a program that will receive data from serial port, the data will end in "\r\n". I am using `Data_Received` event to receive the data from the serial port.

Below is my program, I am try to avoid to use Thread.Sleep and use thread to wait for the data fully receive, but the step always jump to the `return "Error"` step.

I would like to know how to let the program to wait for the data fully receive before it jump to the `return "Error"` step?

It will be fine if don't use thread and if someone have a better method to do.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortExample
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 


string port1ReceivedMessage = string.Empty;

internal delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHandlerDelegate(
                 object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e); 

SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();

string InputData = string.Empty;
delegate void SetTextCallBack(string text);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

   comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

}

~Form1()
{
    comPort.Close();
}

public string SendDataAndReadData()
{
    port1ReceivedMessage = string.Empty;

    string sendData = "?";
    Send(sendData); // To send data

    Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    t.Name = "Thread_1";
    t.Start();

    //Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(port1ReceivedMessage) && port1ReceivedMessage.Contains("\n"))
    {
        event_1.Set();
        return port1ReceivedMessage;
    }

    return "Error";


}

private void ThreadProc()
{

    event_1.WaitOne();

}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    InputData = comPort.ReadExisting(); 

    if(InputData != string.Empty)
    {
      try
      {

      this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallBack(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
      }
     catch (TimeoutException timeoutEx)
     {
        //Skip exception handling codes
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //Skip exception handling codes
     }
    }
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
    port1ReceivedMessage += text;
}

private void portOpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comport = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    comport.ReadTimeout = 2000;
    if (!comport.IsOpen)
    {
        comport.Open();
    }

 }

private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SendDataAndReadData();
}

private void Send(string text)
{
    // Skip some text formatting codes 
    comPort.Write(text);
}

}
```

Comment: I think you have a wrong understand of how threads work. The instruction t.Start() immediately comes back as the thread is processed in the background.

Comment: Without seeing where port1ReceivedMessage is set any answer would be a guess but for sure the Set() and WaitOne() are in the wrong place/ used wrong all together. Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: BTW: Why would you want to avoid Thred.Sleep()?

Comment: If you are using the SerialPort class then you could use are not using the ReadLine method

Comment: There is no benefit to using DataReceived or a thread at all, just makes it harder to reason through and debug.  Simply call ReadLine().  Once you've got it working you'll want to set the ReadTimeout property so you avoid a misbehaving device from hanging your program.

Comment: @rene I had edited the question and added the completed code.

Comment: @LosWochos It is to receive some data that send in inconstant time, it I use Thred.Sleep(), I worry it will receive multiple data after the delay.

Comment: Just read the answer from MarkusEgle and re-implement  what is in the mentioned blog or try Hans's suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I will try with MarkusEgle's method, but should I change comPort.ReadExisting() to comPort.ReadLine()? Isn't it what you guys mean for "using ReadLine()"?

Comment: Using ReadLine() normally works in more then 99% of all cases. If you are communicating with an device in an industrial environment 24h/7d, then you should consider to use the BaseStream property.

Comment: @MarkusEgle Yes, ended up just a simple Readline() solved my problem, but I got some useful information from your answer,so I accepted your answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read:

[If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

That is a blog post from Ben Voigt written 2014 on sparxeng.com.

Excerpt:

> To put it mildly, [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) was designed by computer scientists operating far outside their area of core competence.  They neither understood the characteristics of serial communication, nor common use cases, and it shows.  Nor could it have been tested in any real world scenario prior to shipping, without finding flaws that litter both the documented interface and the undocumented behavior and make reliable communication using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort (henceforth IOPSP) a real nightmare.

and

> The worst offending System.IO.Ports.SerialPort members, ones that not only should not be used but are signs of a deep code smell and the need to rearchitect all IOPSP usage:
>
> - The DataReceived event (100% redundant, also completely unreliable)
> - The BytesToRead property (completely unreliable)
> - The Read, ReadExisting, ReadLine methods (handle errors completely wrong, and are synchronous)
> - The PinChanged event (delivered out of order with
>   respect to every interesting thing you might want to know about it)

and

> And the one member that no one uses because MSDN gives no example, but is absolutely essential to your sanity:
>
> - The BaseStream property

Despite that blame from Ben Voigt, we are using the `BytesToRead` property and the `ReadExisting()` including `Thread.Sleep()`. We avoid `DataReceived()` and `ReadLine()`. That was our workaround, we didn't know the BaseStream property as well.

For new projects I would recommend to use the `BaseStream` property.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataRecieved` event fires somewhat randomely.  You won't always get the whole string when it fires.  Thankfully, you know what your message looks like once you have the whole thing. You need to build up your string until you see a `/r/n` then do what you need to do once you know you have the whole string.

```
private StringBuilder sb;
private SerialPort sp;

public void init_state_machine()
{
    sp = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Clear();
}

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentLine = "";
    string Data = sp.ReadExisting();

    Data.Replace("\n", ""); //remove new lines

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == '\r')
        {
            currentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

As for sending, you can just do your send and when the device responds your `DataRecieved` event will fire.  The `DataRecieved` event is already in its own thread so you don't need to handle all the threading stuff you are trying to do.